# How get a list objects from map in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json like this: And a wanna get Task list and create a list in flutter

```
"data":{
  "task":[
     {
        "date":2021-03-27,
        "done":false,
        "task":"opa",
        "time":2021-03-27,
        "uuid":065eb891-8cee-4942-88b5-a51710558860,
        "uuid_user":we9pdNcS0IUj8yYBx3Wu07yRufx2
     },
     {
        "date":2021-03-28,
        "done":false,
        "task":opa22,
        "time":2021-03-27,
        "uuid":583ba261-25c7-4d5e-8724-a5edd61b93f8,
        "uuid_user":we9pdNcS0IUj8yYBx3Wu07yRufx2
     }
  ]
```

}
}`

Answer (score 0):

here is your task list please try

```
void main() {
 var mapList = {"data":{
  "task":[
     {
        "date":"2021-03-27",
        "done":false,
        "task":"opa",
        "time":"2021-03-27",
        "uuid":"065eb891-8cee-4942-88b5-a51710558860",
        "uuid_user":"we9pdNcS0IUj8yYBx3Wu07yRufx2"
     },
     {
        "date":"2021-03-28",
        "done":false,
        "task":"opa22",
        "time":"2021-03-27",
        "uuid":"583ba261-25c7-4d5e-8724-a5edd61b93f8",
        "uuid_user":"we9pdNcS0IUj8yYBx3Wu07yRufx2"
     }
  ]
} };
  
   mapList.forEach((key, value) {
     value.forEach((key, taskList){
       print(taskList);
     });
   
 });
}
```

Comment: Your are Welcome!!